# How do I create a Grails skeleton project for plugin development?

Tags: grails

I am working with a (sort of) framework built on top of Grails. This framework is a set of Grails plugins that add functionality to the Grails app (e.g. user authentication). This framework is a bit of a pain to setup, as it requires around 64 lines of site specific configuration in the apps's `Config.groovy` file.

I want to develop my addons to this app as plugins. That is, the Grails app would really just be a set of installed plugins and some configuration files.

I have created a local Maven style repository to hold all of my plugins. Thus, I can add plugin dependencies to the `BuildConfig.groovy` file and they will be installed automatically (side question: is it possible to specify the install order?).

So my question is, how do I create skeleton project for developing my plugins that would:

1. Include the base configuration for my application (the aforementioned 64 lines)
2. Allow me to do a `grails package-plugin` to package *only* the plugin's code

Comment: This question is so old that I no longer even have the project. So I can't determine an actual answer to accept. I'd close it or delete it if I could (there's no close category for "do not care any more").

Answer (score 0):

You can use the post-installation hooks mechanism: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html#hookingIntoBuildEvents

Answer (score 0):

Not really an ideal setup for me, but the following works:

1. Create the "base" application: `cd ~/GrailsDev/ && grails create-app my-app`
2. Configure `my-app` as desired/required
3. Create your dependent plugin: `cd ~/GrailsDev/ && grails create-plugin my-app-plugin`
4. Add the new plugin to the app by editing "~/GrailsDev/my-app/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy" and appending the line: `grails.plugin.location.'my-app-plugin' = "../my-app-plugin"`

You can now run the `my-app` Grails application and the plugin will be included. When your plugin is fully developed, you can do `grails package-plugin` from within the "~/GrailsDev/my-app-plugin" directory to package your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

use gradle. you can specify the order and package your plugin alone.

e.g. include the required plugins as git modules (for easy versioning) and gradle modules (for building your plugin) in your plugin project.
this setup will serve your requirements well I suppose.

https://github.com/grails/grails-gradle-plugin

IntelliJ does have a template for gradle-backed grails applications and plugins.